How to determine if an ntfs partition (inside VHDX) is dirty?
I have a VHDX file containing a single NTFS partition, when I mount this VHDX using Disk Management it's determined to be "dirty":

I do indeed have some issues reading this disk until I run ChkDsk on it, so the message is correct.
I want to check, programmatically, if a partition needs ChkDsk before attempting to read it and after reading NTFS documentation from here and here I understood the Dirty flag should be set in the $Volume file in the $VOLUME_INFORMATION attribute:

However if I read this information the Dirty flag is not set as can be seen from this hex dump:

However, after mounting (and without making any further changes) with Disk Management the dirty flag is immediately set:

So how does Windows determine the disk is dirty if the flag was not set?
And if I cannot use the dirty flag, how can I determine it programmatically?
In this example the disk is from Windows 7 and the partition is MBR style. There are no other partitions in the VHDX.
EDIT
Found the following extra information in Windows Internals 7th edition part 2 (page 709):

The dirty bit has a slightly different meaning compared to previous editions of Windows. The $VOLUME_INFORMATION attribute of the NTFS root namespace still contains the dirty bit, but also contains the P-bit, which is used to require a Proactive Scan, and the F-bit, which is used to require a full check disk due to the severity of a particular corruption. The dirty bit is set to 1 by the file system driver if the p-bit or the F-bit are enabled, or if the $Corrupt stream contains one or more corruption records.

So it looks like the P-Bit (Proactive scan bit) or the F-Bit might be set. Unfortunately I haven't found information where this bits are stored. Perhaps in 2nd byte of the flag field which is a USHORT ?
